# How to programmatically query Neo4J auto index (as opposed to legacy index)

Tags: neo4j

I have a numeric auto index defined:

```
val db = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
  .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(dbPath.getAbsolutePath)
  .newGraphDatabase()

neo.schema.indexFor(USER_LABEL).on(PROP_CURSOR).create()
```

I'd like this index to be used for numeric queries (I'm interested in nodes with the lowest "cursor" property). However, I can't find how best to do this in the API documentation. Any suggestions?

I'd prefer to avoid legacy Neo4J indexes as they're cumbersome to maintain, and I couldn't find a way to update a value in a legacy index.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `GraphDatabaseService#findNodesByLabelAndProperty` method (available on your `db` val).

There's good documentation example of this here: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-new-index.html

Comment: I'm looking to run numeric queries (finding the node with the lowest property). I'm not trying to find a node by single property or label.

Comment: Ok. For that you'll need to use the legacy node_auto_index and associated methods, as the schema indexes currently support only exact lookup.